# UnknownProducerIdException in Kafka streams when enabling exactly once

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

After enabling exactly once processing on a Kafka streams application, the following error appears in the logs:

```
ERROR o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamTask - task [0_0] Failed to close producer 
due to the following error:

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [0_0] Abort 
sending since an error caught with a previous record (key 222222 value 
some-value timestamp 1519200902670) to topic exactly-once-test-topic- 
v2 due to This exception is raised by the broker if it could not 
locate the producer metadata associated with the producerId in 
question. This could happen if, for instance, the producer's records 
were deleted because their retention time had elapsed. Once the last 
records of the producerId are removed, the producer's metadata is 
removed from the broker, and future appends by the producer will 
return this exception.
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.recordSendError(RecordCollectorImpl.java:125)
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.access$500(RecordCollectorImpl.java:48)
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl$1.onCompletion(RecordCollectorImpl.java:180)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$InterceptorCallback.onCompletion(KafkaProducer.java:1199)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:204)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:187)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:627)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:596)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:557)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.handleProduceResponse(Sender.java:481)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.access$100(Sender.java:74)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender$1.onComplete(Sender.java:692)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:101)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:482)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:474)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownProducerIdException
```

We've reproduced the issue with a minimal test case where we move messages from a source stream to another stream without any transformation. The source stream contains millions of messages produced over several months. The KafkaStreams object is created with the following StreamsConfig:

- StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG = "exactly_once"
- StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG = "Some app id"
- StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG = 1
- ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG = 102400

The app is able to process some messages before the exception occurs.

Context information:

- we're running a 5 node Kafka 1.1.0 cluster with 5 zookeeper nodes.
- there are multiple instances of the app running

Has anyone seen this problem before or can give us any hints about what might be causing this behaviour?

### Update

We created a new 1.1.0 cluster from scratch and started to process new messages without problems. However, when we imported old messages from the old cluster, we hit the same UnknownProducerIdException after a while.

Next we tried to set the `cleanup.policy` on the sink topic to `compact` while keeping the `retention.ms` at 3 years. Now the error did not occur. However, messages seem to have been lost. The source offset is 106 million and the sink offset is 100 million.

Comment: The producer ID is store directly in the log -- thus, if all your data gets deleted, it could happen that the PID is lost. What is your retention time and what timestamps do your data have?

Comment: The retention time of the source topic and destination topic is set to 3 years. What do you mean with the producer ID being stored in the log?

Comment: To be specific, we have set retention.ms to 3 years and cleanup.policy to delete

Comment: Are message timestamps older than retention time? Producer ID of the writing producer is store for each message and the log is used as "source of truth" what PIDs are known (PIDs are not store again somewhere else). Might also be a bug on the broker of the producer... Not sure.

Comment: The retention times set for both the source and sink topics are 3 years, and the oldest message we have is 6 months old. The sink topic is brand new, and so is the Kafka streams application we are using for reproducing the problem. Another thing to note is that the cluster was upgraded from 0.11 to 1.0.1 to 1.1.0 over the course of 6 months. We are in the process of setting up a new 1.1.0 cluster now from scratch to see if that helps.

Comment: I've dug through the ProducerStateManager code and I think maybe isProducerExpired has a bug. If I understand it correctly, producers are deemed expired when processing records with old timestamps. @MatthiasJ.Sax can you confirm?

Comment: I am not familiar with the details of the KafkProducer code -- but it is certainly possible that there is a bug. Maybe, you can just create a Jira and describe your findings (if it's not a bug, not a big deal).

Comment: I registered https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6817

Comment: About messages getting lost: kafka offsets are not guaranteed to be continuous so you cannot draw any conclusions about message counts by comparing offsets in source and sink.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, there currently seems to be a bug that may cause problems when replaying messages older than the (maximum configurable?) retention time.

At time of writing this is unresolved, the latest status can always be seen here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6817